# How can I add some extra information to a django admin edit view?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to be able to include some information surrounding a users profile in the admin edit view. Is there a simple way of extending the edit view to include some arbitrary html?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution I found so far are readonly fields, see

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

The most important in those is the fact that you can not only put fixed strings there (also HTML) but also functions which return anything

Comment: IMHO the best solution if you just want to display some additional information and setting help_text is not feasible enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can [override admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `help_text` argument is a useful approach. Depending on the template layout you use, the `help_text` value is added right next to the HTML form field markup. Here is an example:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Never change this name!")
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document_name
```

The above code gives you the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own change view and create template for it which will contain some additional info ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.history_view)). But this will only work for chosen admin panel. Another possibility is to create admin directory in your templates and override default template (you have to containt path to this dir in your TEMPLATE_DIRS setting), but i am not sure of this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at using change_view. Here are the docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view